# Convert String to item number, then pass to activity to API

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, matching

I'm developing an Android app. I have a spinner that I can find what item was selected from it. I need to be able to match up the item selected to a number, and then pass that off to another activity to perform an API request. I'm not sure how to do this. I've looked for solutions to this problem, but I haven't found very clear instructions that I can follow. I found that I could use `Map<String, String>` to do the matching part, but how can I retreive the number of the one selected from that? Would I just search inside the Array for `SelectedValue`, and how would that be done? I know that I can do `startActivityforResult();` to transfer the number to the next activity. I also am not sure how to add that `number` to the url, like http://google.com/`number`. My code is below:

**Part of TestStation.java**

```
        Spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String selectedValue = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                int[] Yellow_ID = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.Yellow_ID);
                int[] Yellow_Li = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.Yellow_Line);

                HashMap<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
                for (int i = 0; i < Yellow_Line.length(); i++) {
                    myMap.put(Yellow_Li[i], Yellow_ID[i]);
                }




        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match pair of String - Number values, you can use String -> Number map. For example:

```
Map<String, Integer> pairs = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
pairs.put("key1", 25);
pairs.put("key2", 10);
```

Then, you use it like this:

```
Integer value = pairs.get("key1"); // value = 25
```

Does this solve your matter?

**Edition after your comment:**

```
Map<String, Integer> posibleSelectedValues = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
posibleSelectedValues("possibleKey1", respectiveValue1);
posibleSelectedValues("possibleKey2", respectiveValue2);
posibleSelectedValues("possibleKey3", respectiveValue3);
posibleSelectedValues("possibleKey4", respectiveValue4);
posibleSelectedValues("possibleKey5", respectiveValue5);
```

Then:

```
String userSelectedValue= user_selected_option;
Integer correspondingValue = posibleSelectedValues.get(userSelectedValue);
```

Comment: The only other thing would be to compare them. I have around 100 items, so would I have to do `if value=somestring Integer value = pairs.get("key1"); // value = 25, if value=otherstring Integer value = pairs.get("key2"); // value = 10`?

Comment: No, you can do directly:
`Integer intValue = pairs.get(strValue);`

Maybe I have not undestand correctly your problem.

If you want to match String with Intger you can use Map<String, Integer>, but you can also use Map<String, String>, Map<Integer, String>, Map<Integer, Integer> and any you like it.

The main rule to use maps is that they containts pairs of key -> value, both can be any type of Objects

Answer (score 0):

You could have the items in your spinner be enums if the values aren't dynamic.

```
mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Value>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Value.values()));

        Spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
            Value selectedValue = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            //Get whatever you want from it
    }
```

Example enum

```
public enum Value {
  BLAH("key1",1,"myToStringVal"), MORE_BLAH("key1",1,"myToStringVal");
  Value(String key, int value, String name) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.name = name;
  }   

  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }
  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}
```